# JPA one-to-one relationship without column mapping

Tags: jpa

I have a couple of entities with one-to-one relationships as such:

```
@Entity(name="stores")
public class Store implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id ;
    // How should I set goal ?
    private Goal goal ;
}
```

and:

```
@Entity(name="storeGoals")
public class Goal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column(name="goalId")
    private int id ;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "storeId")
    private Store store ;

}
```

My problem is how can I set the "goal" field in the Store entity?

Normally, I would do something like:

```
@Entity(name="stores")
    public class Store implements Serializable {
       ...
       @OneToOne() 
       @JoinColumn(name = "goalId")
       private Goal goal ;
       ...
```

but in this case I can't, because the underlying "stores" table belongs to another application and can't be modified (by adding a "goalId" column).

What I need is for an instance of Store to be able to lookup its goal by finding a record in the storeGoals table that has the same storeId (Realizing of course that I could run into referential integrity issues...)

Any ideas on how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What storegoals table?  Are you not just looking to reuse the Goal.storeId foriegn key relationship, or is there a relational table 'storeGoals' that exists to map the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for what is known as a bidirectional OneToOne relationship.  This works the same as a bidirectional ManyToMany or OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship in that one side 'owns' the relationship and has control over setting the value in the foreign key; the other specifies it is 'mappedby' the other side, and so operates as if it is read-only.  Both sides need to be kept in synch with any changes manually though; if you set one side but do not reflect the change in the other, JPA will not fix this for you.

In this case:

```
public class Store implements Serializable {
  ..
  @OneToOne(mappedby="store")
  private Goal goal ;
}
```

Comment: It was so simple I'm ashamed I had to ask!